# Exception with :jshint-junit-reporter

Tags: npm, gruntjs, jshint

I wrote a demo for jshint with Grunt, code listed below:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('jshint-junit-reporter');
    grunt.initConfig({
        jshint: {
            all: ['Gruntfile.js'],
            reporter: require("jshint-junit-reporter"),
            reporterOutput: "junit-output.xml"
        }
    });
};
```

and got exception:

[image]

Here is the result of jshint-junit-reporter installation:
[image]

and related software version:
npm: 3.10.8
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v1.0.1
nodeJS: v0.12.7 
I really appreciate any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reporter**: and **reporterOutput**: are both options and should be specified in an options block. Try updating your task to:

```
jshint: {
    all: ['Gruntfile.js'],
    options: {
        reporter: require("jshint-junit-reporter"),
        reporterOutput: "junit-output.xml"
    }
}
```

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint